# Having problems properly converting a String to an int to insert into SQL database with a field type of Number

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to insert an entry into a database using a form created in java. I am able to select from the database without issue, but am having difficulty inserting to it. The issue, I believe, is that I am not converting the integers properly, or perhaps SQL does not take in an int into a Number field. I am not sure. I keep getting a "AWT-EventQueue-0" error, but it is not specifying where.

Here is a snippet of my code for converting my input text:

```
public void addItem() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Item i1;
    DataAccess DA = new DataAccess();
    this.txtOutput.setText(DA.testResult);
    i1 = new Item();
    i1.setItemId(Integer.parseInt(this.txtItemId.getText()));
    i1.setCategoryId(Integer.parseInt(this.txtCategoryId.getText()));
    i1.setItemName(this.txtItemName.getText());
    i1.setItemDesc(this.txtItemDesc.getText());
    i1.setUnitPrice(Integer.parseInt(this.txtUnitPrice.getText()));
    i1.setUnitStock(Integer.parseInt(this.txtUnitStock.getText()));
    try {
        i1.saveItem();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.txtItemId.setText("");
    this.txtCategoryId.setText("");
    this.txtItemName.setText("");
    this.txtItemDesc.setText("");
    this.txtUnitPrice.setText("");
    this.txtUnitStock.setText("");
}
```

Also, here is the code I am using to then insert that data into my database:

```
public int saveItem() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    int rowsAffected=0;
    String strSQL = "INSERT INTO item VALUES (sc_item_item_id_seq.NEXTVAL," + this.getCategoryId() + ",'" + this.getItemName() + "','" + this.getItemDesc() + "'," + this.getUnitPrice() + "," + this.getUnitStock() + ")";
    DataAccess DA = new DataAccess();
    rowsAffected = DA.modifyDatabase(strSQL);
    return rowsAffected;
}
```

Like I said, I am trying to input integers into fields in my database that are of type Number. Is this doable, or am I mistaken?

Also of note, I have this working without issue on another table, but that table is only taking in strings.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit:

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at javagui.views.frmItem.addItem(frmItem.java:243)
at javagui.views.frmItem$1.actionPerformed(frmItem.java:101)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If an exception is thrown, show us its stack trace. And please use prepared statements: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Do the ItemName or itemDesc fields contain unfriendly characters, such as quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it correctly; inserting the numeric type values without quotes. However, I believe your error is coming from the `Integer.parseInt()` you are doing in `addItem()`. Please check that all the strings you are trying to parse to ints are not faulty. You should also put these `Integer.parseInt()` statements in `try/catch(NumberFormatException)` block as well to catch these conversion errors.

Also, since you are doing the `try/catch` for the exceptions you are looking for, you don't need to specify what the function throws in the function header. That is to tell the upper level calling functions "Hey, I might throw these exceptions, so you need to catch them."

Comment: +1! I completely forgot the exception. I delete my answer not to pollute yours :) Nice catch.

Comment: Thanks. I added the try/catch (NumberFormatException) and it seems to be catching the errors. From what I see, I don't think there are any faulty characters in the strings that are being converted. I'll keep trying. :)

Comment: I caught it. I was leaving the ItemId field blank, as I have a sequence that generates the item_id for me when inserting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading and understanding the stack trace.

It tells you that the problem is a `NumberFormatException` for the input String `""`:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

, happening when calling `Integer.parseInt`:

```
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
```

in the method `addItem` of your class `frmItem`, at line 243 of the file frmItem.java:

```
at javagui.views.frmItem.addItem(frmItem.java:243)
```

It thus has nothing to do with the database: you're passing an empty String to `parseInt`. Error messages and stack traces are really useful: you must read them and try to understand them.

Comment: Thanks. I am still very new to Java. That's quite helpful. I'll look for that in the future.